# I want to pass python an argument via command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I type `python` in a shell I get `>>>` as a result. Then if I type `print "something"`, it prints something. I want to do both in a single command via bash script. Here is an example that doesn't work but is close to getting the point across

```
`print "something"` | python;
```

I would expect python to be executed and the print command to be passed as an argument. But this is not the case.

How can I do this:

```
python
>>> print "hello"
```

in one command?

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
python -c "print 'hello'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write it as

```
echo 'print "something"' | python
```

or

```
printf 'print "something"' | python
```

but Bhajun's answer is what you really want.